# Looping through arrays - python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I am trying to create a 4x2 (2x4 works too) matrix by taking values from two other 10x10 matrices. So far, this is all I could come up with:

```
for k in range(no_of_elements):
    element.append([])
    i2 = k/range_y 
    element[k].append(mx[i2+1][j+1]) 
    element[k].append(mx[i2+1][j])
    element[k].append(mx[i2][j])
    element[k].append(mx[i2][j+1])
    element[k].append(my[i2+1][j+1])
    element[k].append(my[i2+1][j])
    element[k].append(my[i2][j])
    element[k].append(my[i2][j+1])
    j += 1
    if j == range_y:
        j = 0
```

where `range_x` and `range_y` are 9 and `no_of_elements` is 81. `mx` and `my` are 10 x 10 matrices. I have a fair understanding of how to access the elements of an array using indices but I couldn't understand how to name an array with an index. In my case, what I want is a way to do this:

```
for i in range(no_of_elements):
    element[i] = ('A 4x2 Matrix')
```

By this I mean, I need to create 81 matrices and each one must be named `element[1]`, `element[2]` etc. so that I can loop through `no_of_elements` again to perform further calculations on these matrices. If someone could help me understand how I can achieve this, it would be really helpful. If that is not possible, I just need a way to loop through a `value(no_of_elements)` and create a few matrices and be able to call them one by one. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to deal with numeric matrices, numpy is way to go

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I have been reading numpy documentation on array indexing but I couldn't find a way to index an array when I'm passing values to it. Can you please explain how I can use numpy to do this? Even a link would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: if you want to be able to retrieve them by "name", you could consider storing all of the matrices in a dictionary.   For your matrix construction, it is difficult to see what you wish to accomplish. Right now, element[z] is a list, not a matrix.  In numpy, you can construct empty arrays(matrix) like: np.zeros((4,2)) and then fill it in.  Also, if you start with a list that is 8 long, you can make it into a 4x2 by "reshaping" using numpy (google it).

Comment: @user1269942 Thank you. I think storing them in a dictionary is the way to go.